# Why am I getting segmentation error in a Caesar cipher program?

Tags: c, cs50

I'm trying to write a program that uses Caesar's algorithm to cipher a string input. I'm a beginner to C but I can understand basic codes. So to cipher the text I wrote this code, but when I enter the input, I get an error that says

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I tried to do some debugging by removing the else condition at the end and the program kind of worked for short inputs of 2-3 letters

Can someone please help me with this issue?

I'm using the CS50's header only to get the string in the first place.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{

    char name[] = "";
    strcat(name, argv[1]);
    int key = atoi(name);
    string plaintext = get_string("plaintext: ");
    int length = strlen(plaintext);
    char ciphertext[] = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        int skipCount = 0;
        if(isalpha(plaintext[i]))
        {
            while(skipCount < key)
            {
                char tmp = (char) ((int) plaintext[i] + 1);
                if(isalpha(tmp))
                {
                    ciphertext[i] = tmp;
                    skipCount++;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (isupper(plaintext[i]))
                    {
                        tmp = 'A';
                        skipCount++;
                    }
                    if (islower(plaintext[i]))
                    {
                        tmp = 'a';
                        skipCount++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else ciphertext[i] = plaintext[i];
    }
    printf("%s\n", ciphertext);
}
```

Comment: 'strcat(name, argv[1]);' name is too short for anything useful to be catted to it, so, not no reason:(

Comment: Nothing happens fo no reason. Your `name` variable should hold more space in order to copy data into it.

Comment: How can I edit it to hold more characters?

Comment: `char name[] = "";` defines an array with size for 1 byte (initialized to `'\0'`).

Answer (score 2):

What you need to understand about C, is that it does not automatically allocate memory.

You have to it your self!

This line:

```
char name[] = "";
```

creates an array of size 1, which holds a single character - the "null" character = '\0';

It signifies an empty string.
You can not copy any larger string in to it, because all strings in C must have a null character at the end, so there isn't enough room for even a single readable character.

As a beginner, you would need to decide what the maximum length of the string you want will be, and declare the array to be of proper size:

```
char name[255];
```

This is one example that can hold up to 254 characters, plus the terminating null character.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, I knew that I could decide the maximum length of the string array but I thought this would make the program somewhat incomplete. I guess it's the way to to it as a beginner.

Comment: @ÖzgünCanOrhan you could do an `strlen` on `argv[1]` than use `malloc` to dynamically allocate the array, but that is a more advanced topic.